# Se puede devolver datos de dos tablas en un Icollection usando LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

esta es mi primera pregunta, espero hacerlo correctamente.

Estoy empezando a utilizar webAPI en .net Core y tengo una duda, tengo los siguientes modelos:

```
public class Pokemon
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }

        public ICollection<PokemonOwner> PokemonOwners { get; set; }

        public ICollection<PokemonCategory> PokemonCategories { get; set; }

    }

public class Categoría
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public ICollection<PokemonCategory> PokemonCategories { get; set; }

}

public class PokemonCategory
{
        public int PokemonId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public Pokemon Pokemon { get; set; }

        public Categoría Categoría { get; set; }
}
```

Estoy tratando de mostrar en un endpoint de mi controlador donde me muestra juntos los pokemones y su correspondiente categoría.

He intentado hacer un join entre las dos tablas pero es imposible obtener el resultado esperado ( Devolver los pokemons y su categoría)

```
public ICollection<PokemonCategory> GetPokemonAndCategory(int pokemonid, int categoryid)
        {
            return _context.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == categoryid)
                .Join(_context.Pokemon.Where(p=> p.Id == pokemonid))
                .ToList();
        }
```

¿me pueden ayudar? ¡gracias!

*** EDIT ***
Ahora obtengo el siguiente resultado, pero sin el pokemon ni la categoria :S

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Water",
    "pokemonCategories": [
      {
        "pokemonId": 2,
        "categoryId": 2,
        "pokemon": null,
        "category": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Que quieres: un pokemon con todas sus categorías que tiene,  o una categoría con todos los Pokemon que la poseen?

Comment: Una categoria con todos los Pokémons, pero si me puedes enseñar también como hacer un Pokémon con todas las categorías te lo agradecería!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework utiliza el LEFT JOIN de manera natural por lo que no es necesario realizar dicho JOIN con linq

En tu modelo Categoría ya tiene una lista de PokemonCategory. Esto se llama propiedades de navegación.

El problema es que existen [3 métodos para cargar datos relacionados](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/?source=recommendations), y distintas versiones de .net utilizan distintas de forma default

Si estas útilizando .net core, .net 6 o .net 7 deberás colocar un include

```
public List<PokemonCategory> GetPokemonAndCategory(int categoryid)
{
     return _context.Categories.Include(a=> a.PokemonCategories ).ThenInclude(a=> a.Pokemon).Where(c => c.Id == categoryid).ToList();
}
```

Al convertirlo en JSON debes tener especial cuidado con los problemas circulares. Esto sucede cuando la clase1 tiene una propiedad de navegación a la clase2 y ésta última tiene una propiedad de navegación a la clase1

Comment: Me da el siguiente error;  System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PokemonReviewApp.Models.Category]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[PokemonReviewApp.Models.PokemonCategory]'.'

Comment: Cambien el retorno por lista (tú lo tenías así), prueba nuevamente

Comment: Puedes leer mi edit? GRACIAS!!!

Comment: @mancha1 Puedes clarificar lo que realmente quieres, cuál sería el JSON que esperas (no tiene que ser exacto), me interesa saber cuál es la clase principal

Comment: Siento ser tan torpe, realmente ahora analizandolo el JSON que me gustaría es el siguiente; [
  {
    "pokemonCategories": [
      {
        "pokemon": id, nombre, fecha nacimiento,
        "category": id, nombre
      }
    ]
  }
]

muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @mancha1 No te preocupes. Pero el problema es que sigo sin entender. De todas maneras edité la respuesta con una nueva para que vayamos descartando (ojo que dejé la función con un solo argumento)

Comment: Perfecto!!! he hecho unos pequeños cambios pero me devuelve lo siguiente;

[
  {
    "pokemonId": 1,
    "categoryId": 1,
    "pokemon": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Flix",
      "birthDate": "2022-10-24T15:39:22.956",
      "reviews": null,
      "pokemonOwners": null,
      "pokemonCategories": [
        null
      ]
    },
    "category": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Electric",
      "pokemonCategories": [
        null
      ]
    }
  }
]

Si quisiera eliminar la parte de review, pokemon owner etc, supongo que tendria que ser con un DTO??

Comment: No es necesario ocupar DTO, puede ocupar el decorator [JsonIgnore] en la propiedad que no quieres que vaya, o si solo no quieres mostrar lo cuando sea null colocas [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]

Comment: Gracias!!!!!!!!!